# js-beautify indentation of case labels

Tags: javascript, indentation, js-beautify

js-beautify, when used from the command line (latest version, on both Windows and Linux) indents case labels, leading to double indentation of case blocks. I posted this as an issue on github:

https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/issues/367

in reply to which someone correctly pointed out that it actually works properly when you use it via the web interface, which suggests it might be a configuration problem rather than an actual bug in the code.

Does anyone know what's causing this, and whether there's a way to fix it with a configuration tweak?

Comment: In your issue, you mentioned installing jsbeautify with `npm`. When I try that, I get a `deprecated jsbeautify@0.3.6: This version is not maintained. Please check js-beautify` warning. Have you tried installing with `pip` instead?

Comment: @StephenThomas Tried with `pip` just now and it still doesn't work properly, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the option `--good-stuff` on the command line, e.g.

```
js-beautify --good-stuff -f test.js
```

Comment: @rwallace are you planning to give him that bounty?

Comment: @ManofSnow yes, didn't realize it hadn't done it when I accepted the answer, done now.

Comment: @rwallace Close call :)

Comment: What exactly "good stuff" does? Documentation is unclear (deliberately)